# Jquery search filter not work after load ajax content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a sample code

```
Search:<input type="search" class="form-control" id="search">
<table id="gwAssignForm"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

And my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "content.php",
      data: {},
      async : false,
      success: function(result) {
         $('#gwAssignForm tbody').html(result.html);
      },
      error : function(xhr, status){
         console.log(status);
      },
   });
   var $rows = $('#gwAssignForm tbody tr');
   $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
   });
});
```

on content.php

```
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
```

After load ajax content. I start search, but it not work. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't working because you are trying to add elements to `$rows` before your ajax data is loaded.  You just need to declare `$rows` within your `keyup` function.

Simply change this -

```
var $rows = $('#gwAssignForm tbody tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

to this -

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var $rows = $('#gwAssignForm tbody tr');
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since table data is dynamically added `$rows` will be the initial rows inside the table, so you need to update `$rows` after table data added dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $rows = $('#gwAssignForm tbody tr');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "content.php",
      data: {},
      async : false,
      success: function(result) {
         $('#gwAssignForm tbody').html(result.html);
         $rows = $('#gwAssignForm tbody tr');
         // update '$rows' after table content is added
      },
      error : function(xhr, status){
         console.log(status);
      },
   });
   $('#search').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();    
        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
   });
});
```